# Get capital characters as string using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to get capital letters by:

```
"My Name Is".chars()
.filter(c-> c > 64 && c < 97 )
.collect(<??>);
```

I am not sure what I should pass to collect() method to get list of characters or a string.

My object is to parse string and get another string which has only capital letters

This works fine :

```
StringBuilder abbr=new StringBuilder();
"My Name Is".chars()
            .filter(c -> c > 64 && c < 97)
            .forEach(c->abbr.append(Character.toChars(c)));
```

Is is possible to use collect() construct of even a better /shorter way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.joining("")`.

```
String upper = "My Name Is".chars()
                           .filter(Character::isUpperCase)
                           .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char)c))
                           .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Note that I also use `Character.isUpperCase`.

Comment: `Character.isUpperCase`. Doesn't that violates the predicate interface ? .However its interesting

Comment: @sakhunzai Why would it violate it?

Comment: I mean it is usually 1param -> return bool1 format. I am just learning. Could you also add some description what collect() construct expects .Thanks

Comment: Well you have one param (the int) and isUpperCase will return a boolean so I don't see where the contract is violated. For the collect, look at the javadoc it's well explained. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: You don’t need to specify an empty `String` as in `Collectors.joining("")`. If you don’t want a separator, you can use `Collectors.joining()`

Answer (score 2):

```
String result =
    "My Name Is".chars()
                .filter(c -> c > 64 && c < 97)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                         (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c),
                         (sb1, sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2.toString()))
                .toString();
```

Comment: or `.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)`.